# How do I can change a variable with go command line?

Tags: ubuntu, go

My problem is `go run someprogram.go usecomand change_variable=value` is this possible and how I can make it?

```
import (
        "github.com/spf13/cobra"

        "fmt"
        "math/rand"
        "time"

        "github.com/brocaar/lorawan"

        MQTT "github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang"
        lds "github.com/iegomez/loraserver-device-sim"

)

func mainCmd() *cobra.Command { 
     return &cobra.Command{ 
         Use: "sensor", RunE: func(cmd *cobra.Command,args []string) error {
         ip := "tcp://127.0.0.1:1883" 
         cmd.Println("O IP da gateway e o port são:",ip) 
    //Connect to the broker 
    opts :=MQTT.NewClientOptions() opts.AddBroker(ip)
```

See this is what my go file contains and I want in command line build the go file and execute and change the ip variable

Comment: Are you asking about changing environment variables (that remain changed after your Go app terminates); or changing variables defined and used inside your Go app?

Comment: Hi thank your for your reply. Imagine that I want o change the port of an IP address, like `localhost:8080`, and then when I'm in command line I make the go file and execute like this `./name_of_go_file command_name and here I need like a variable to change the port 8080 to 8000`

Comment: ` 

func mainCmd() *cobra.Command {

        return &cobra.Command{
        Use: "sensor",
                RunE: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) error {


        ip := "tcp://127.0.0.1:1883"
        cmd.Println("O IP da gateway e o port são:",ip)


        //Connect to the broker
        opts := MQTT.NewClientOptions()
        opts.AddBroker(ip)


`

Comment: Please edit your question with the code samples you have. In general, you may use package [`flag`](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/) to get command line arguments into Go variables.

Comment: I'm using cobra not the package ` flag`

Comment: https://github.com/spf13/cobra/blob/master/README.md#working-with-flags

Answer (score 3):

you can change the variables during build with `go run -ldflags="-X..`. flags.

In this example, change the ip to become a variable at the start of your code.

```
var IP = "<default_ip>"
```

Then you can reference the variable in the rest of your code. Then run the code with

```
go run -ldflags="-X <package>.IP <new_ip_address>" program.go
```

So if your package is `main`, and the program name is `main.go` and the new IP is `0.0.0.0` you would run

```
go run -ldflags="-X main.IP 0.0.0.0" program.go
```

I used this however in my testing (with an `=` sign, since it errored)

```
go run -ldflags="-X main.who=0.0.0.0" program.go
```

You can read [this article here for more information](https://blog.cloudflare.com/setting-go-variables-at-compile-time/)

Comment: It is not necessary to have the main-function in a main.go file, it can be in any file in the package main. It is confusing that you mention main.go in your explanation, but have program.go in your example

Comment: after reading and execute, it can add the `Hello CloudFlare`.

Answer (score 1):

usually it is used in devops pipeline to embed a build number.
the format is a bit tricky in Go:

1. you declare in some file a public `var BuildNumber string` . do not initialize it.
2. take module name (hint:its in the 1st line in `go.mod`).
3. concat the folder path from project root to the target filename from step 1. take the package name from that file (hint: 1st line)
4. concat the variable name (case sensitive) use dot as delimiter.
5. assign an override value to complete the ldflag input for that variable.(1.0.200)

```
go build -ldflags "-X [module_name_from_go_mod]/[subfolder1]/[subfolder2]/[package_from_filename_which_contains_var].BuildNumber=1.0.200"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change value of variable inside the code, you can use command line arguments.
You can refer https://gobyexample.com/command-line-arguments

Comment: But I want to change the variables to another value. Imagine I got a variable which name's ip=80, and in command line I want to change ip=10

Comment: use len(os.Args) in that case. If its <2 use your default option else use the value you passed in command line

Comment: Sorry but I use that like `    argsWithProg := len(os.Args)`

Comment: I can't see anything

Comment: initially let ip=80 then check if len(os.Args) < 2 then ip=80 else ip=os.Args[1].

Here in the args[1] you will pass the value 10 as ' go run program_name.go 10'

Comment: yeah. The os.Args[1] should contain the value that you want to assign to the variable ip

Comment: https://pastebin.com/043VwAY3 - check this. I gave you the pseudo code. This is a example of how to be implemented

Comment: `gateway@gateway:~/go-learn/ub_test/another$ go run main.go 15
2
15
gateway@gateway:~/go-learn/ub_test/another$ go run main.go 
1
80
`
The problem is that still has the old number and I want to change

Comment: I need that example to string is possible?

Comment: I can do it, but my problem is that I got a cmd cobra every time i run ` ./gateway sensor 80` don't work