# using ldflags for giving binary file a version not working in golang

Tags: go

The main.go as follows:

```golang
package main

func main() {
    println("hello world")
}
```

The Makefile as follows:

```
flags=-X main.version=1.5.0

build:
    go build -ldflags "$(flags)" -o main main.go
```

Then I run `make`, and got main file.

After I runing `./main -v`, I just got:

```
hello world
```

Why it does not display `1.5.0`?

go version is `go version go1.18 darwin/arm64`, when I run  `go version -m main`, I got:

```
main: go1.18
        path    command-line-arguments
        build   -compiler=gc
        build   -ldflags="-X main.version=1.5.0"
        build   CGO_ENABLED=1
        build   CGO_CFLAGS=
        build   CGO_CPPFLAGS=
        build   CGO_CXXFLAGS=
        build   CGO_LDFLAGS=
        build   GOARCH=arm64
        build   GOOS=darwin
```

---

I had a misunderstanding of `ldflags`. It works as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

var (
    version string
)

func main() {
    args := os.Args
    if len(args) == 2 && (args[1] == "--version" || args[1] == "-v") {
        fmt.Printf("project version: %s \n", version)
        return
    }
}
```

```sh
$ ./main -v 
project version: 1.5.0
```

Comment: I found the reason it noe working. I may use `os.Args` to accpet `-v` flag. It is a misunderstanding of `ldflags`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable you're setting with ldflags (`version`) must be declared in the package at the package level. The handling of `-v` you yourself must implement.

```golang
package main

import "flag"

var version string

func main() {
    var vFlag bool
    flag.BoolVar(&vFlag, "v", false, "show version")
    flag.Parse()
    
    if vFlag {
        println(version)
    } else {
        println("hello world")
    }
}
```

```sh
go build -ldflags "-X main.version=1.5.0" -o main main.go
./main -v
# 1.5.0
./main
# hello world
```

Comment: see my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/75970021/2132826

Answer (score 2):

If one builds a package (as in `go build github.com/xxx/yyy/zzz` then the symbol must be prefixed accordingly.  For example:

```bash
go build \
    -ldflags "-X github.com/xxx/yyy/zzz/main.version=1.5.0" \
    -o my-awesome-app \
    github.com/xxx/yyy/zzz
```

B.T.W. Another way to figure out which symbol ID to use is to run [`nm`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nm) and grep for the variable you are looking for.

Comment: see my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/75970021/2132826

Answer (score 0):

This comment is not an answer for the actual question but is related to the title. Therefore, I think it is worth sharing here.

One reason why ldflags may seem not to be working is that it works only for string type variables.

Example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

var sss = "FOO"
var ccc = 2

func main() {
        fmt.Println("variables:", sss, ccc)
}
```

- Executing this code with `go run main.go` displays `variables: FOO 2`
- Executing it with `go run -ldflags="-X main.sss=BAR" main.go` displays `variables: BAR 2`
- Executing it with `go run -ldflags="-X main.ccc=5" main.go` displays `main.ccc: cannot set with -X: not a var of type string (type.int)`

Another gotcha is you get no error message if `-X`  is missing. It just doesn't do what you expect:

- Executing it with `go run -ldflags="main.sss=BAR" main.go` displays `variables: FOO 2`